# ¿Cómo actualizar la Clase Persona de mi código?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, arraylist, bucles, clase

¿cómo podría actualizar la clase persona? No me actualiza los datos. Este es mi código, se queda trabado y no me sale ni un error:

**public void listar(Persona per)  {**

```
        tablePersona.ColumnCount = 6;
        tablePersona.Columns[0].Name = "Nombre";
        tablePersona.Columns[1].Name = "Apellidos";
        tablePersona.Columns[2].Name = "Sexo";
        tablePersona.Columns[3].Name = "Fecha";
        tablePersona.Columns[4].Name = "Cuidad";
        tablePersona.Columns[5].Name = "Estado";
        tablePersona.Rows.Add(per.Nombre,per.Apellidos,per.Sexo,per.Fecha,per.Cuidad,per.Estado);
```

}

**private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){**

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= personas.Count; i++)
        {
            if (txtNombre.Text==personas[i].Nombre)
            {


                txtApellidos.Text = personas[i].Apellidos;
                txtSexo.Text = personas[i].Sexo;
                txtFecha.Text = personas[i].Fecha;
                txtCiudad.Text = personas[i].Cuidad;
                txtEstado.Text = personas[i].Estado;
                personas.Add(per);

            }

        }
        listar(per);
        limpiar();
    }
```

[image: Error se queda trabado]

Comment: Tu codigo pasa los datos de un array a los textbox en pantalla, y despues agrega a una lista? un objeto per que no esta definido en ningun lado que se vea.. o sea.. no hace nada de lo que decis que deberia hacer. no se como podriamos ayudarte...

Comment: Estan declaradas globales  List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>(); y Persona per = new Persona();

Comment: que significa "actualiza la clase persona" queres que cuando cambien un textbox se actualize el valor de la lista?

Comment: tu programa tiene un bucle infinito. Wlimina la linea  personas.Add(per);

Comment: si eso estoy intentando mi logica jaja :c estoy recorriendo un for para que me agarre el indice de lista y con ese indice cambiarla por los txtbox y despues almacenarlas con el Add

Comment: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección. me sale ese error si lo elimino

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a StackOVerflow, y bienvenido a la programacion :)

El problem en tu codigo es que personas.Count se va agrandando adentro del loop, porque vuelves a agregar la persona una y otra vez. o sea, tu codigo hace eso:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= personas.Count; i++)
 {            
     personas.Add(per);
 }
```

Aqui un codigo de ejemplo de como podrias hacerlo. Hay mejores maneras de hacer esto, pero intente hacer el codigo de la manera mas sencilla posible :)

```
public void LimpiarListar(List<Persona> personas) 
{

    // Primero tienes que limpiar
    tablePersona.Controls.Clear();

    // Luego agregar todas las personas
    tablePersona.ColumnCount = 6;

    tablePersona.Columns[0].Name = "Nombre";
    tablePersona.Columns[1].Name = "Apellidos";
    tablePersona.Columns[2].Name = "Sexo";
    tablePersona.Columns[3].Name = "Fecha";
    tablePersona.Columns[4].Name = "Cuidad";
    tablePersona.Columns[5].Name = "Estado";

    foreach(Persona pers in personas)
    {    
        tablePersona.Rows.Add(per.Nombre,per.Apellidos,per.Sexo,per.Fecha,per.Cuidad,per.Estado);
    }
}

private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    foreach(var persona in personas)
    {
        if (txtNombre.Text == persona.Nombre)
        {
            persona.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text;
            persona.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
            persona.Fecha = txtFecha.Text;
            persona.Cuidad = txtCiudad.Text;
            persona.Estado = txtEstado.Text;

            // persona ya esta en la lista, asi que no hay que actualizar la lista
        }

    }
    limpiarYlistar(personas);
}
```

Comment: Estaba leyendo el otro codigo pero no lo llegue a probar, y esta ultima si pero me crea otra persona no me actualiza :c, gracias recien estoy aprendiendo a programar uu

Comment: no puede ser :)  persona es una clase o un struct?

Comment: quizas tu problema esta en listar() y limpiar. que hay ahi? no deberias limpiar primero y luego listar?

Comment: Es una Clase, puede que mi listar tenga un Problema te lo edito arriba, gracias por tu tiempo, el limpiar lo hace al registrar ahi puse el metodo.

Comment: Listo añadí listar pero no lo pude ordenar bien por el mismo Stackoverfloww aun estoy aprendiendo

Comment: te falto poner el limpiar

Comment: El limpiar solo limpia los datos de la caja de texto

Comment: actualice el codigo. No tengo windows en este momento asi que no puedo testear el limpiar :( - lo importante es que tienes que saber que primero tienes que borrar todo del tablePersona, y luego agregas a las personas. en tu codigo solo agregas a la nueva persona sin borrar la anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Aca en tu metodo te falta pasarle la persona actualizada, ya que Per, que es tu objeto que quieras actualizar y agregas en tu List no lo estas actualizando.

//Este deberia ser tu metodo buscar.

```
  private void Buscar (object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <= personas.Count; i++)
    {
        if (txtNombre.Text == personas[i].Nombre)
        {
         txtApellidos.Text = personas[i].Apellidos;
         txtSexo.Text = personas[i].Sexo;
         txtFecha.Text = personas[i].Fecha;
         txtCiudad.Text = personas[i].Cuidad;
         txtEstado.Text = personas[i].Estado;
       }
}
```

// y asi tu metodo actualizar.

```
private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Persona per;

 foreach (Persona per in personas)
 {      
     if(per.Nombre == TxtNombre.Text)
       {
            per.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
            per.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text;
            per.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
            per.Fecha = txtFecha.Text;
            per.Cuidad =  txtCiudad.Text; 
            per.Estado =  txtEstado.Text;
       }
  listar(personas);
}
```

Entiendo que tu metodo ListarPersona esta mal, porque esta rellenando un grid donde deberia cargar un listado de personas y solo le pasas una Persona.

```
public void listar(List<Persona> personas) 
{

    tablePersona.ColumnCount = 6;
    tablePersona.Columns[0].Name = "Nombre";
    tablePersona.Columns[1].Name = "Apellidos";
    tablePersona.Columns[2].Name = "Sexo";
    tablePersona.Columns[3].Name = "Fecha";
    tablePersona.Columns[4].Name = "Cuidad";
    tablePersona.Columns[5].Name = "Estado";
    foreach (var per in personas)
   {  
    tablePersona.Rows.Add(per.Nombre,per.Apellidos,
                          per.Sexo,per.Fecha,per.Cuidad,per.Estado);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Ya lo Arregle pero con DataSource xd

Comment: ok, si la respuesta corrigio tu problema, dale como aceptada y el datasource es la forma mas comun de agregar, solo respete la forma que tu lo haces.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a Todos por Ayudarme, eh aprendido Muchísimo con su ayuda como el problema del bucle infinito el Parametro persona que tenia que arreglarlo con List<> y el ForEach de verdad me ayudo GRACIAS POR SU TIEMPO!!

Bueno yo lo que estuve averiguando y es hacerlo con un **DataSource** más fácil pero me *quedo con mal gusto* xd :C y entendí bien, aunque me falta más averguar ese **Método(DataSource)**. Aqui el Codigo si alguien lo necesita y recien esta Aprendiendo como yo, solo me falta validar los textbox a ver si averiguo algo como hacerlo con ERRORPROVIDER.

```
 private void btnRgistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            Persona per = new Persona();
            //Proceso de Registra                
                per.Dni = int.Parse(txtDNI.Text);
                per.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
                per.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text;
                per.Edad = int.Parse(txtEdad.Text);
                per.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
                per.Fecha = dtpFecha.Value;
                per.Cuidad = txtCiudad.Text;
                per.Estado = txtEstado.Text;
                personas.Add(per);

            tablePersona.DataSource = null;
            tablePersona.DataSource = personas;
            limpiar();

            //String[] per=new string[] {txtNombre.Text, txtApellidos.Text, txtSexo.Text,
            //txtFecha.Text,txtCiudad.Text, txtEstado.Text};



        }
```

```
 private void btnActualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (Persona mipersona in personas)
            {
                if (mipersona.Dni == int.Parse(txtDNI.Text))
                {
                    mipersona.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
                    mipersona.Apellidos = txtApellidos.Text;
                    mipersona.Edad = int.Parse(txtEdad.Text);
                    mipersona.Sexo = txtSexo.Text;
                    mipersona.Fecha = dtpFecha.Value;
                    mipersona.Cuidad = txtCiudad.Text;
                    mipersona.Estado = txtEstado.Text;
                    break;

                }
            }
            tablePersona.DataSource = null;
            tablePersona.DataSource = personas;
        }
```

Comment: excelente, no te quise decir lo del datasource para no complicarlo mas. tampoco el `break;`  pero veo que avanzas a pasos agigantados, felicitaciones y a seguir programando! :)

Comment: otra cosa que podrias mejorar es usar Linq. Puedes hacer `mipersona = personas.First(p => p.Dni == int.Parse(txtDNI.Text))`

Comment: Vale lo pondre como comentario util gracias C:

Comment: @EduardoFelipeDuffautMolina has colocado una pregunta como respuesta. Quitala por favor.